# Tufte-handout table of contents font problem with kpfonts and lualatex

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, luatex, tufte

I am trying to use `kpfonts` with `tufte-handout` class. For some reason the table of contents font defaults to Computer Modern roman when compiled with `lualatex`, rest of the document compiles correctly. The same code with `xelatex` compiles correctly and the table of contents font is italics of `kpfonts`. How can I get correct font for toc using `lualatex`?

[image: XeLaTeX compiles correctly]

[image: LuaLaTeX defaults only TOC font to CM]

MWE

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[]{kpfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}             

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{LuaLaTeX}
\lipsum

\section{Two}

\lipsum
\section{Three}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: T1 encoding and legacy fonts like kp don't really make a good fit wih luatex as you have to disable most of its unicode support, why not use pdftex?

Comment: It compiles correctly with pdflatex with this error "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/kpfonts.sty:94: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                               
l.94 ...textcomp\RequirePackage[full]{textcomp}\fi                                                  \fi? "

Comment: yes I believe that has been reported to the package maintainer

Comment: I am also using some other font familes which need use of lua/xelatex, and microtype which doesn't like xelatex. So using pdflatex makes it difficult to get the document compiled. But what I am not able to get is why is only the toc font affected? Rest of the document gives the italics fine!

Comment: latex does warn you `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`TU/jkp/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using \`TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 1.`
something is detecting luatex and switching back to unicode and so breaks the legacy 8bit kp font setup. It's probably fixable but....

Comment: I finally got it working by specifying the required fonts for toc using `tocloft` such as `\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large\itshape}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile with LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX), I suggest you use the Opentype version of the kpfonts:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{LuaLaTeX}
\lipsum

\section{Two}

\lipsum
\section{Three}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

PLease have a look at the documentation `Kpfonts-OTF-Doc-English.pdf` for more information about the available options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I got it working by specifying the required fonts for toc using tocloft such as \renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large\itshape}